# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance- docker compose with ASP.NET Core 2.1 and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

Docker compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  legalregtech.web.host:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}legalregtechwebhost
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/LegalRegTech.Web.Host/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - dev-net
    ports:
      - "22742:80"
    depends_on:
      - sqlServer
  
  sqlServer:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    environment:
        ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
        SA_PASSWORD: 'XXXXX'
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      - dev-net
    volumes:
      - /C/Databases/SqlServer/Data:/var/opt/mssql/data 
networks:
  dev-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.172.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.172.0.1
```

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/LegalRegTech.Web.Host/LegalRegTech.Web.Host.csproj", "src/LegalRegTech.Web.Host/"]
COPY ["src/LegalRegTech.Web.Core/LegalRegTech.Web.Core.csproj", "src/LegalRegTech.Web.Core/"]
COPY ["src/LegalRegTech.Application/LegalRegTech.Application.csproj", "src/LegalRegTech.Application/"]
COPY ["src/LegalRegTech.AzureCosmosDB/LegalRegTech.AzureCosmosDB/LegalRegTech.GraphDBConnector.csproj", "src/LegalRegTech.AzureCosmosDB/LegalRegTech.AzureCosmosDB/"]
COPY ["src/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared.csproj", "src/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared/"]
COPY ["src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj", "src/LegalRegTech.Core/"]
COPY ["src/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared.csproj", "src/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared/"]
COPY ["src/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "src/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/LegalRegTech.Web.Host/LegalRegTech.Web.Host.csproj"
COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish "LegalRegTech.Web.Host.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LegalRegTech.Web.Host.dll"]
```

I get this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.CreateAndOpenConnection()
> at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection[T](DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Func`2 func)     at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection(DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Action`1 action)
> at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.Initialize()
> at LegalRegTech.Web.Startup.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /src/src/LegalRegTech.Web.Host/Startup/Startup.cs:line 149

SQL Server is running fine, I am able to connect through SSMS in local computer. I think in the container the app is not able to connect to the SQL Server.

When running `docker-compose up` a network get created as below

[image]

It gets created with the suffix 6clicks_ which is the root folder of my application and when I do the inspect on that network the container is {}

```
[
    {
        "Name": "6clicks_dev-net",
        "Id": "b6f693ce2402e7c52d0c8af3048eaebd86ed19b41a43dca381f30712c00f4193",
        "Created": "2021-12-10T02:34:23.8790393Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.172.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "dev-net",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "6clicks",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.0.0"
        }
    }
]
```

Connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Data Source=127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=sa; Password=xxxxx; Persist Security Info=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
}
```

The reason I can see on the docker logs is  `Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 172.172.0.2]`. However I am able to login in with SSMS with same password

Comment: Are you seeing the new error message about the password mismatch after you tried my answer? or before?

Comment: Yes I am getting the same error after the update

Comment: Is it something somewhere I need to enable the security ?? Firewall or something ?? not sure Just asking

Answer (score 0):

Since `legalregtech.web.host` is not configured to connect to `sqlServer` explicitly, it tries to connect `127.0.0.1` as configured in your `appsettings.json` file.

For use within docker-compose, it's easiest to simply override this connection string to reach the `sqlServer` service by adding an environment variable:

```yaml
  legalregtech.web.host:
    # ...
    environment: 
      - ConnectionStrings__Default=Data Source=sqlServer; Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=sa; Password=xxxxx; Persist Security Info=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

(A more compact connection string would be: `Server=sqlServer;Database=xxxxx;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`)

---

Here's a fully working docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:

  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    environment:
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=zHDgRw7qw4QJyrrhgXK2mG45
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    
  dotnetapp:
    image: dotnetapp
    depends_on: 
      - mssql
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment: 
      - ConnectionStrings__Default=Server=mssql;Database=amplily;User ID=sa;Password=zHDgRw7qw4QJyrrhgXK2mG45;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

Comment: still facing the same issue, didn't solve the issue

Comment: @SanJaisy I've updated my answer with a full example